# Importance of using TransactionScope

Tags: nhibernate, transactions

What is the difference between using

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
        {
        using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
        {
            using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                session.Delete(entity);
                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
        scope.Complete();
        }
```

and simply using ?

```
using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
        {
            using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                session.Delete(entity);
                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
```

What are the advantages and disadvanteges and when they are appropriate to use?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using both *TransactonScope* and *NHibernate transaction* you have some kind of duplicated logic. If you want to operate with simple SQL Transaction than you should use *NHibernate transaction*.

[TransactionScope class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) is designed to use in *any* general transaction scenario. For example it is used in EntityFramework. While using NHibernate you don't need it, but it becames very useful when you need to [implement custom transaction mechanism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172152.aspx).

Comment: That's not correct. TransactionScope is to manage a distributed transaction, NH ITransaction is to manage the NH transaction and is always needed.

Comment: Please clarify your comment to make me able to correct my answer. What exactly is not correct?

Comment: Might I suggest having a look at the ncommon framework (http://github.com/riteshrao/ncommon) it demonstrates an ORM-agnostic unit of work implementation that uses a TransactionScope

Comment: Good example, but useless in real life applications.